# Can I use the google translate api in my standalone application

Tags: java, translation

I'm ready to pay for google translatebut i want to know that can i use the google translate api in my standalone application which can be able to translate with out using internet

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this offline. Google exposes this functionality via a RESTful Web Service.